# Weird whitespace in browser while making responsive page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Disclaimer: This is some weird whitespace that glitches.
I was making a Image slideshow using html, css and js. But after I added images like this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="slides-container">
        <div class="slide-image">
          <img src="./public/assets/ironman.png" alt="captain" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide-image">
          <img src="./public/assets/captain.png" alt="captain" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide-image">
          <img src="./public/assets/blackwidow.png" alt="captain" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide-image">
          <img src="./public/assets/blackPanther.png" alt="captain" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.slides-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.slide-image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide-image img {
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(80%);
}
```

But this is showing some weird white space after my footer. When I removes the Images this issue is fixed i.e. this issue is caused by images only.

[image: Bottom Whitespace]

But the actual issue is really confusing as this whitespace sometimes just disappears out, by just stretching the browser window and sometimes reappears out of nowhere. This really confuses me as it doesn't show any particular breaking point.

Here I did nothing to any code, but just refreshed the browser and did some stretching browser window. And now it's fixed.

[image: fixed bottom whitespace]

And after few more stretches and after another refresh the whitespace reappeared.
What could be done. Please ignore the other part of the html, they're not any issue.

I'm so confused. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the problem but I've had a similar issue in the past. I don't know if it's exactly the same but your images are absolutely positioned. That removes them from the document flow.

Try setting a background color on the wrapper and recreate the glitch. That'll tell you if you're seeing the wrapper as the white space. If that's the case (and maybe even if not) you could try putting something relatively positioned with 100% width and height before the images. They'll absolutely position themselves above it.

I don't like it as a solution but without recreating it myself I can only guess.